# Error with getting creation date with BasicFileAttributes?

Tags: java, nio

well i have 4 files in a folder , 3 of i made yesterday and one now.
When i try to get their creation date, i get 4 all the same :

```
[29/06/14 3:35 PM]: 2014-06-28T22:57:37.79051Z
[29/06/14 3:35 PM]: 2014-06-28T22:57:38.282064Z
[29/06/14 3:35 PM]: 2014-06-28T22:57:37.79051Z
[29/06/14 3:35 PM]: 2014-06-28T22:57:31.76595Z
```

but however i did not make all 4 of them on june 28, one of them is actually june 29.
refer to this picture :

[image: File View]

my code :

```
folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Customer/Source/Data/Backups/" + username + "/");
        File[] backups = folder.listFiles();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(backups));
        for (File backup : backups) {
            if (backup.isFile()) {
                Path file = Paths.get(backup.getAbsolutePath());
                BasicFileAttributes bfa = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
                String backup_date = bfa.creationTime().toString();
                System.out.println(backup_date);
}
```

Comment: What file system are you using? Not all file systems support creation date.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same issue. My files are on a windows server (don't know exactly what version 2003 or 2008) and I tested the utility with JDK 1.7 and 1.8. I ended up writing a C# utility that does the same thing and it works correctly. It's extremely odd.